# Windows phone WebClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient, vk

I am use WebClient to get page from web, 
when i get google start page all ok
but when i get page from vk api WebClient return Serer not found, but browser open this page normal
my code:

```
private void log_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string auth;
    string login = Uri.EscapeUriString(this.login.Text);
    string password = Uri.EscapeUriString(this.pass.Password);
    auth = "https://api.vk.com/oauth/token";
    auth += "?grant_type=password" + "&client_id=id&client_secret=code&username=" + login + "&password=" + password + "&scope=notify,friends,messages";

    //auth = "https://google.com/";

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted +=new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
    Uri.EscapeUriString(auth);
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(auth));
}
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
         MessageBox.Show("Using WebClient: " + e.Result);

    else
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
}
```

Comment: Oftentimes issues like this posted on the wp7 stack-overflow always end up being that a https connection is made to a server with an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens only for `https` calls with non-`200` response status. If you receive `Not found` with right credentials, check out your request parameters.

Try this workaround for non-`200`:

```
client.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
```

Also, I see this line `Uri.EscapeUriString(auth);` which I think must be `auth = Uri.EscapeUriString(auth);`

Comment: I change my code, and insert your code after WebClient client = new WebClient(); but this doesnt work

Comment: If you call this request from a browser, authentication is successful?

Comment: Try HttpWebRequest instead of WebClient. It's work for me if authorization is successful.